# looking to scrape text from reddit.io

Tags: r, web-scraping

I used the code below to return all comments from the link I provided, but it isn't returning anything. I used the same method on the reddit site itself and it worked, but Reddit doesn't give me all the posts in the subreddit's history, so im using reddit.io instead. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

read_html("https://redditsearch.io/?term=depressed&dataviz=false&aggs=false&subreddits=ucdavis&searchtype=comments&search=true&start=0&end=1630465448&size=227") %>%
  html_node("div#comments") %>%
  html_nodes("div.body") %>%
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  
  html_text()
```